# Update with paragraph in text

Tags: mysql

I have for example this text:

```
magnalister-Verarbeitung (Amazon)
Marketplace Bestellnummer: 303-8945805-5911960
```

I want to replace this with nothing.

```
magnalister-Verarbeitung (Amazon)
Marketplace Bestellnummer: 


UPDATE s_order SET `internalcomment` = REPLACE(`internalcomment`, 'magnalister-Verarbeitung (Amazon)
Marketplace Bestellnummer: ', '');
```

This statement doesn´t work because there is a paragraph between 
(Amazon) AND Marketplace

Can somebody help with this issue?

If I do it in two steps it works like this:

```
UPDATE s_order SET `internalcomment` = REPLACE(`internalcomment`, 'magnalister-Verarbeitung (Amazon)', '') 

UPDATE s_order SET `internalcomment` = REPLACE(`internalcomment`, 'Marketplace Bestellnummer: ', '')
```

But thats not a really good solution :-(

Comment: `UPDATE s_order SET internalcomment = '' WHERE ordernumber = 205077` is not what you want?

Comment: No, because the number will be deleted, too.

This ist the whole text: magnalister-Verarbeitung (Amazon)
Marketplace Bestellnummer: 303-8945805-5911960
removed should only the text: magnalister-Verarbeitung (Amazon)
Marketplace Bestellnummer:

Comment: Sorry I mistook your intend then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to replace the new line too:

```
UPDATE s_order SET `internalcomment` = TRIM(REPLACE(`internalcomment`, 'magnalister-Verarbeitung (Amazon)\nMarketplace Bestellnummer: ', ''));
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d972d4ff8c1a99a1ae04d52ab85c58b6)

You can also use a dynamic solution like this:

```
UPDATE s_order SET `internalcomment` = TRIM(REPLACE(`internalcomment`, SUBSTR(`internalcomment`, 1, LOCATE(':', `internalcomment`)), ''));
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c85b02a8188481eb8e57cf449653ecbc)

To replace until the second `:` you can use the following solution:

```
UPDATE s_order SET `internalcomment` = TRIM(REPLACE(`internalcomment`, SUBSTR(`internalcomment`, 1, LOCATE(':', `internalcomment`, LOCATE(':', `internalcomment`) + 1)), ''))
WHERE `internalcomment` LIKE '%User Name:%';
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=17d9894eb309ce7e114f09d5bf5c36ef)

Comment: I tried your dynamic solution oh an other problem. Here is the text:

magnalister-Verarbeitung (eBay)
Marketplace Bestellnummer: 253922962415-2401084620015


eBay User Name: beatgruedfn50

If the Text contain 'User Name' than do the following Statement:

UPDATE s_order
SET `internalcomment` = REPLACE(`internalcomment`, 
SUBSTR(`internalcomment`, 1, LOCATE(':', `internalcomment`)), '')
WHERE `internalcomment` LIKE 'User Name'

This solution isnt working. Do you have a Idea why?

Comment: Just a last question. It is the second ':' in the string. Is there a possibility the use the second one, otherwise i need to run the query two times.

Comment: to get the second `:` you need to use the following `REPLACE` instead: `TRIM(REPLACE(internalcomment, SUBSTR(internalcomment, 1, LOCATE(':', internalcomment, LOCATE(':', internalcomment) + 1)), ''))` - see also the update

Comment: An other solution would be:

UPDATE s_order
SET `internalcomment` = REPLACE(`internalcomment`, 
SUBSTR(`internalcomment`, 1, LOCATE(':', `internalcomment`,86)), '')
WHERE `internalcomment` LIKE '%User Name%'

Comment: @ChristianMazilu - contains your second comment real data (username)? if so you can delete this comment.